# I have add a apps (BC API DISCOVERY ) in adobe business catalyst. But after add this app then showing a message in yellow box

Tags: adobe, business-catalyst

I have add a apps (BC API DISCOVERY ) in adobe business catalyst. But after add this app then showing a message in yellow box like

(This application is already installed on your site - but it needs to be authorized in order to function.Please contact your developer to authorize the app to run on your site and access your data.)

Please check also a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsEK1.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article - http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/developers/faqs/api-related-faqs#authorize-first

Basically you can copy the files from one site to the other, however, the first time you need to authorize the app. To do this log on with a partner user and you will have a button to authorize the app.

Do note the site you are authorizing the app for needs to be under your own partner portal.

If you are still having trouble let me know:

-the site you are trying to install the app on

-the app key

-the username you are logging in with

Thanks

Aayush Vashishtha